# how can I determine if 3 points can make a circle or form a circle?

Tags: circles

given three points, how can I determine if they lie on the same circle? I just want to determine if they can form a circle or not.

for example, do P(2,1), Q(0,5) and R(-1,3) lie on the same circle??

thx all!

Comment: The only case they won't is if all three are on a line.

Comment: Even then, one might consider it a degenerate circle with infinite radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $3$ points form a triangle then the circumscribed circle passes through all of them.

Thus you have to check for the degenerated case where the points are aligned, a condition could be $\vec{PQ}\wedge\vec{PR}=\vec 0$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle

Answer (score 0):

solve the System
$$(2-x_M)^2+(1-y_M)^2=R^2$$
$$(0-x_M)^2+(5-y_M)^2=R^2$$
$$(-1-x_M)^2+(3-y_M)^2=R^2$$